# How can I add a textfield dynamically after clicking a button?

Tags: java, button, wicket, textfield

Can anyone point me in the right direction here. Im wanting to have say 2 textfields initially then the user will be able to click 'add' button and another 2 textfields will be displayed (this needs to be dynamic as the user could click once or a 100 times for example)

Comment: you should probably retag you question or at least say what coding language are you talking about

Answer (score 5):

Since it's wicket, it should be Java... I would retag this but my account is to new for that...

Put your initial Textfields models into a single wrapper-object and add this to a list (thus containing only one element) and display this list in a ListView. In the onClick Event of your Button, add another of these wrapper-objects to your list and refresh the ListView.

Something like

```
public class TwoTextFields {
    private IModel textFieldOne;
    private IModel textFieldTwo;

    [... constructor, getters setters here  ...]
```

and

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {

   private List<TwoTextFields> list = new ArrayList<TwoTextFields>();

   public MyPanel(String id) {
       super(id);
       add( New ListView<TwoTextFields>("list", list) {

           @Override
           protected populateItem(Item<TwoTextFields> item) {
               add( new TextField("fieldOne", new PropertyModel(item, "textFieldOne");
               add( new TextField("fieldTwo", new PropertyModel(item, "textFieldTwo");
           }
      });
      add( new Button("button) {

           @Override
           protected void onClick() {
               list.add(new TwoTextFields());
           }
      });
}
```

I don't know if this compiles... It's just to give you the idea, didn't want to fire up eclipse for that...

Comment: This would reload the page instead of updating via Ajax, which could be cleaner.  Should work, though :)

Comment: Why does the backing class TwoTextFields uses instances of IModel as it's properties, instead of just String?

Comment: @jbrookover: yeah, this example isn't ajaxified but since that's just boilerplate in wicket and the example ist just that, an example not a solution of it's own, I thought, that would be sufficient

Comment: @ireddick: Two reasons.... a) that way you can use the same code to add checkboxes and any othe formelement you like by just adding some generics to the wrapper. b) Wicket Textfields can hold much more than just Strings. By using the Model you can easily access the conversion power of wicket to use these fields for numbers etc. as well.

Comment: thanks for the sample code thats given me some good idea. Thanks!