# Java Swing: JButton creates new JTextField(s)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jtextfield

Hello :) I am beginner in Java Swing and I can't google solution for my problem. I have a JPanel and want to add JTextField(s) dynamically after pressing a JButton. And how can I getText() from them later? My code, commented part isn't working properly.

Variable 'counter' counts how many fields I have in panel.

```
public class AppPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField tfData[];
    private JButton btAdd;
    private int counter = 1;

    public AppPanel() {
            setLayout(null);

            //tfData[counter] = new JTextField();
            //tfData[counter-1].setBounds(20, 20, 250, 20);
            //add(tfData[counter-1]);

            btAdd = new JButton("Add field");
            btAdd.setBounds(280, 20, 120, 20);
            btAdd.addActionListener(new alAdd());
            add(btAdd); 
    }

    class alAdd implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //tfData[counter] = new JTextField();
                    //tfData[counter].setBounds(20, 20+20*counter, 250, 20);
                    //add(tfData[counter]);
                    ++counter;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can refer this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522279/how-can-i-add-a-textfield-dynamically-after-clicking-a-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already storing references to your text fields, just use this array to query the text of the text fields:

```
tfData[counter-1].getText();
```

will show you the text of the last added text field.

But you really should initialise your array before, otherwise you won't be able to add any items to it. I think that was your main problem as you commented out your adding-code.

```
// think about how many text fields you will need (here: 16)
private JTextField tfData[] = new tfData[16];
```

If you're using arrays, watch for not breaking over its bounds. But better [use a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522279/how-can-i-add-a-textfield-dynamically-after-clicking-a-button) as proposed in the comments before as it grows dynamically and you won't have to deal with array bounds and can even skip counting (the list does that for you, too).