# Getting content from JTextFields created dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am learning Java with Swing and I have some problems with using `JTextField`. In my program I want to dynamically add a few `JTextFields` with some text:

```
while( (ln = bufFile.readLine()) != null ) {
    // inIdPanel is JPanel
    inIdPanel.add(new JTextField(ln));
}
```

And it works good. However, the content of these `JTextFields` can be modified by users, and later I want to call `getText()` from all of them. Is this possible? How can I do this?

I saw this question: [Java Swing: JButton creates new JTextField(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061748/java-swing-jbutton-creates-new-jtextfields) but this isn't enough to solve my problem (I think using arrays in my case is not a good idea but maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you cannot call `getText()` is that you have not stored a reference to the `JTextField` when you created it. You will need to use an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) or [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) to store the `JtextField`s as you create them so you can call the method on them later. A `collection` will be easier than an `array` because you do not know how many lines you will read in so you want it to be able to grow.

```
List<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList<JTTextField>();
while( (ln = bufFile.readLine()) != null ) {
    JTextField field = new JTextField(ln);
    inIdPanel.add(field);
    fields.add(field);
}
```

Then you can call the `.getText()` from all of them

```
for(JTextField field: fields){
    System.out.println(field.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For an easy solution, just add an `ArrayList<JTextField> textFieldList` and add to the code you posted:

```
while((ln = bufFile.readLine()) != null) {
    textFieldList.add(new JTextField(ln));
    inIdPanel.add(textFieldList.get(textFieldList.size()-1));
}
```

Then, when you want to access the text fields, you simply iterate through them, e.g.

```
for (JTextField jtf : textFieldList) {
    /* Operate on jtf, call methods, etc */
}
```

You could replace the `ArrayList` with an array if there is a defined limit on how many text fields you could add, but the list is nice if that quantity is unknown.